# $f$ twice differentiable function on $[a,b]$; $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $f(c)>0$. atleast one $\eta$ between $(a<\eta<b)$ such that $f''(\eta)<0$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a twice differentiable function on $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $f(c)>0$ for $a<c<b$. Then there is atleast one $\eta$ between $(a<\eta<b)$ such that $f''(\eta)<0$

I have already solved the problem using Mean Value Theorem. But I don't get the intuition behind it. I mean what is the geometric interpretation.

Feel free to rephrase the title.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The intuition is "what goes up, must go down"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is, you have some function which is fixed at zero at the endpoints.

If this function is concave up everywhere, since that would imply that the function would attain no positive values on the interval, i.e. that maxima will be at the endpoints. Since you have at least one positive value, there has to be a point of concave down somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it now. :)